# Remove empty entries from list

Tags: r

How can I identify and remove entries in a list that are empty, but aren't NA or NULL. Why does my list appear to be a factor when I try to compare its elements?

```
> s <- subset(world, (oil == "Yes") & !is.na(effectiveness) & !is.null(effectiveness), select = effectiveness)
> s
        effectiveness
3   32.62411409517834
30  31.91489350429382
41                   
54   23.8770690651932
64  35.93380642839076
80   33.3333332769696
81   35.6973993299137
116   50.118203450602
131 20.09456253502668
181                  
194 19.62174974716583
> typeof(s)
[1] "list"
> sum(s)
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
> s[s > 0]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : > not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: looks like you might have a space or bunch of spaces, so your column 'effectivenes' is a type of factor ( when you loaded it). try searching for that and replacing the spaces with ""

Comment: `s` is a data.frame. `typeof` returns the underlying storage type, not the class. It's hard to know why `s$effectiveness` is a factor without knowing how you created `s`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich `world` is a data frame. You can see how I created `s` in the first line above.

Comment: do sapply(world, class) and see what class effectiveness is.

Comment: @infominer It says `effectiveness` is a factor. How do I make it type "double"?

Comment: look at @JoshuaUlrich answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s` is a data.frame. `typeof` returns the underlying storage type, not the class. It's hard to know why `s$effectiveness` is a factor without knowing how you created `s`.

You can [convert a factor to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/271616) via:

```
s$effectiveness <- as.numeric(levels(s$effectiveness))[s$effectiveness]
```

Comment: Thanks! That appears to work. Why can't I take the mean of the result? I get that the typeof the result is "double", yet when I try to apply `mean`, I get NA.

Comment: mean(n, na.rm=T), as the as.numeric will introduce NA's where you have blanks